# TypeError: __call__(): incompatible function arguments.The following argument types are supported:

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I used face_recognition.

**At first**
I could run this could when all things are default (model=HOG)

```
import cv2
import face_recognition

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

Nichapa_im1 = face_recognition.load_image_file("C:\\Users\\ACER\\Desktop\\facetest\\data01\\Nichapa04.jpg")
A_encoding1 = face_recognition.face_encodings(Nichapa_im1)[0]

person_face_encodings = [A_encoding1]
person_face_names = ["NICHAPA"]

data_locations = []
data_encodings = []
data_names = []
frameProcess = True


while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    resizing = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
    rgb_resizing = resizing[:, :, ::-1]
          
    if frameProcess:
        data_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_resizing)
        data_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_resizing, data_locations)
        data_names = []
        for dc in data_encodings:
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(person_face_encodings, dc)
            name = "UNKNOWN"
            if True in matches:
                first_match_index = matches.index(True)
                name = person_face_names[first_match_index]

            data_names.append(name)
           
    frameProcess = not frameProcess
    for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(data_locations, data_names):
        top *= 4
        right *= 4
        bottom *= 4
        left *= 4
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 20), (right, bottom), (255, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX  
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 0.7, (255, 255, 255), 2)
        
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('x'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**What I did**
I changed the detection model to cnn in api.py (model=cnn)
then I ran the same code and I got this error.

```
TypeError: __call__(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: _dlib_pybind11.shape_predictor, image: array, box: _dlib_pybind11.rectangle) -> _dlib_pybind11.full_object_detection

Invoked with: <_dlib_pybind11.shape_predictor object at 0x0000024D4FAC83B0>, array([[[199, 210, 202],
        [199, 210, 202],
        [200, 211, 203],

       ......lots of array here......
        ...,
        [251, 237, 228],
        [251, 237, 228],
        [252, 238, 229]]], dtype=uint8), <_dlib_pybind11.mmod_rectangle object at 0x0000024D4E8705F0>
```

What should I do, i want to use dlib with cnn model

Answer (score 0):

```
loc = face_recognition.api.face_locations(img, number_of_times_to_upsample=1, model='cnn|hog')
```

use this and refer this following link for more

[https://face-recognition.readthedocs.io/en/latest/face_recognition.html][1]